# Julia nested type initialization

Tags: types, nested, initialization, julia, abstract

I used the code below,

```
abstract P0

type P1 <: P0
  x::Float64
  y::Int64
  P1()=new()
end


type P11 <: P0
  z::Int64
  p::P1
  P11()=new()
end
```

and did the below assignment.

```
pp=P11()
```

I obtained **#undef** for the type P1 as the following:

```
P11(2211879264,#undef)
```

**How can I initialize it properly?**

Answer (score 2):

You only need inner constructors if you want to enforce constraints on the field values or need incomplete initialization. The latter is what you did here (note that not only `pp.p` but also `pp.z` is uninitialised).

Otherwise, using outer constructors is preferred, e.g., for setting default values for the fields. For example:

```
abstract P0

type P1 <: P0
  x::Float64
  y::Int64
end

P1() = P1(0.0, 0)

type P11 <: P0
  z::Int64
  p::P1
end

P11() = P11(0, P1())

P11() # returns P11(0,P1(0.0,0))
```

Comment: I wanted incomplete initialization. z was initialized as I reached it by pp.z
Meanwhile I just initialized both of them my modifying the code to:
P11()=new(1,P1())

Comment: I mean I wanted to initialize them with some values first because I will use dynamic arrays read from a file and I don't want initializers out of the type definition together with file reading functions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. In your original code, `pp.z` just interprets the random bits that happen to be at its uninitialized memory location because that field is a `bitstype`. The same is true for the fields of `P1`. On the other hand, `P11().p` is a reference, and therefore is `#undef` until you assign it, e.g., in a constructor or by `pp.p = P1()`. Further, `P11()=new(1,P1())` disables the default constructor and is therefore better written as an outer constructor as in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the info. Is there a way to use value type for p instead of reference type like the structs of Swift?

Comment: I don't know Swift, but that sounds like you should have a look at `immutable` types.